# The tablayout custom font doesn't change

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I'm going to change `TabLayout` custom font but i don't know why it doesn't change any more, i have a 4 tab and a `ViewPager` and have 4 `fragment`. now the problem is that i want to change the tab text font. in fact i used calligraphy for different part but i don't know why i couldn't set it to my own tab. the thing that i use right now is that I developed `FragmentPagerAdapter's` `getTabView` method and set the custom tab there and load the custom tab layout `xml` file in there.

**This is my code:**

```
  package com.example.noavaran.drugstore.Activity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.noavaran.drugstore.Fragment.AddressFragment;
import com.example.noavaran.drugstore.Fragment.IssueFragment;
import com.example.noavaran.drugstore.Fragment.MenuFragment;
import com.example.noavaran.drugstore.Fragment.SearchFragment;
import com.example.noavaran.drugstore.Helper.CustomViewPager;
import com.example.noavaran.drugstore.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import layout.fragment_approve;
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper;
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyUtils;

public class MainPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    public Context context;
    public Typeface tf;
    public static boolean a=false;
    private CustomViewPager viewPager;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.menu,
            R.drawable.address_icon,
            R.drawable.search_icon,
            R.drawable.issue_icon
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);
         tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "IRANSans_Bold.ttf");


        tabCustomization();
        changeTabsFont();
        setupTabIcons();
    }

    private void tabCustomization() {
        viewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);

        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
// Iterate over all tabs and set the custom view

    }
    private void setupTabIcons() {

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);


        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a8a8a8"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a8a8a8"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }
    public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


          adapter.addFragment(new MenuFragment(), "menu");

        adapter.addFragment(new AddressFragment(), "Address");
        adapter.addFragment(new SearchFragment(), "Search");
        adapter.addFragment(new IssueFragment(), "Issue");
        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);

            tab.setCustomView(adapter.getTabView(i));
        }
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }
        public View getTabView(int position) {
            // Given you have a custom layout in `res/layout/custom_tab.xml` with a TextView and ImageView
            View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
            TextView textView= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView.setText(getPageTitle(position));

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView .setImageResource(tabIcons[position]);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }

    }
    private void changeTabsFont() {
       Typeface mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "IRANSans_Bold.ttf");
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
        int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
        for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
            ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
            int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
                View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
                if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                    ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(mTypeface, Typeface.BOLD);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Caligraphy Library
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }
}
```

**and this is my customxml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
        android:gravity="center"
        fontPath="@string/fontsIran"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You have the custom font in 'tf' but where are you setting it for the tab?

Comment: I don't see where you're initializing the `context` field that you're getting the `LayoutInflater` from in `getTabView()`.

Comment: @MikeM. what do u mean about context field in layout inflater

Comment: @SurajRao yes i just update the code

Comment: int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount(); whatvalue are you getting here?

Comment: You have a `Context context` field that you're using for `LayoutInflater.from()`, but the `context` isn't initialized anywhere in your posted code. Also, you're calling `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager()` after calling your `setupViewPager()` method, so all the tabs you're creating are going to be replaced.

Comment: @MikeM. i used  Log.i("TabChild",String.valueOf(tabsCount)); to print but it doesn't show anything

Comment: OK, I don't know where you're calling that, but you've got about four different methods that are trying to modify the tabs, and, frankly, they're kinda all over the place. Really, the code you've posted should be crashing with an NPE, because you call `tabCustomization()`, which calls `setupViewPager()`, which calls `tabLayout.getTabCount()` before `tabLayout` is ever initialized. If you are actually initializing `tabLayout` first, then `getTabView()` is never called, because there are no tabs at that point. If `getTabView()` were called, it would crash, because `context` is null, as mentioned

Comment: Get your `Adapter` setup first, then set it on the `ViewPager`, then initialize `tabLayout`, then `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager()`, and _then_ do everything that you need to do with the tabs customization.

Comment: @MikeM. I didn't get u, would u plz to give me a sample

Comment: I can't really give you any more than the outline, 'cause I can't test atm, and have never used Calligraphy. 1) Setup the `ViewPagerAdapter`. 2) Then set the `Adapter` on the `ViewPager`. 3) Then call `setupWithViewPager()` on the `TabLayout`. 4) Now you have tabs, so here's where you iterate over them, and do the customizations. One more note: you should be using `addOnTabSelectedListener()` instead of `setOnTabSelectedListener()`, or it'll mess up the `TabLayout`/`ViewPager` sync.

Answer (score 0):

use this library.

add this to your build.gradle file

```
//  fonts
compile 'in.workarounds.typography:typography:0.0.8'
```

then change the `TextView` to,

```
<in.workarounds.typography.TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
    android:gravity="center"
    fontPath="@string/fontsIran"
    android:id="@+id/textView" 
    app:font_name="Lato"
    app:font_variant="Light"/>
```

where font is `Lato-Light`.which is located at `assets/fonts/Lato-Light.ttf`